# Inserting a data frame with pandas into SAP HANA quote error

Tags: dataframe, hana

I am running a df.to_sql command which fails because of sqlalchemy error invalid schema name: . The issue is the schema name passed is in small letters thus sqlalchemy removes quotes while generating the sql but SAP hana expects the schema to be in double quotes

code

```
df.to_sql(config.hana["table_name"],
                      schema="tmp_som",
                      con=hana_engine._engine,
                      index=False,
                      chunksize=int(config.hana["chunksize"]),
                      if_exists='append')
```

Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (hdbcli.dbapi.Error) (362, 'invalid schema name: TMP_SOM: line 2 col 14 (at pos 14)')
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE tmp_som."TBL_GTD_RAW" (

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the sqlalchemy and used cursor to execute the code

```
 for i, row in df.iterrows():
                sql = "INSERT INTO \"tmp_som\".\"table_name\" (" +cols + ") VALUES (" + "?,"*(len(row)-1) + "?)"

                cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))

 conn.commit()
```